# Opencv-Python error on when installing PyForms

Tags: python

When I try to install PyForms by 'pip install pyforms', it threw an error:

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/9a/8d9364533ebcaa13621994a63dcc6a6051e27671ae5e1715dac4af18cac2/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
opencv-python==3.4.5.20 (from pyforms-gui->pyforms) (from versions:
3.4.8.29, 4.1.2.30) ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.4.5.20 (from pyforms-gui->pyforms)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary Solution:**

- Download https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/archive/20.tar.gz
- Extract to project directory
- Rename extracted directory to `opencv-python`

Edit `opencv-python/setup.py` and change line 62 to:

```
package_version = "3.4.5.20"
```

Now you can install as normal like:

```
pip install opencv-python/
pip install PyForms-GUI
```

Answer (score -1):

Your version of opencv-python is incompatible with pyforms you need opencv-python 3.4.5.20 try:

uninstall opencv-python

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

install opencv-python 3.4.5.20

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.5.20
```

then you can install pyforms

```
pip install pyforms
```

Comment: there is no version opencv-python==3.4.5.20

Comment: there is look [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.4.5.20/)

Comment: `pip3 install opencv-python==3.4.5.20`
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==3.4.5.20 (from versions: 3.4.8.29, 3.4.9.31, 3.4.9.33, 3.4.10.35, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 4.1.2.30, 4.2.0.32, 4.2.0.34, 4.3.0.36, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.4.5.20

Comment: Idk why it's doing that so I posted a roundabout solution.